# Safari (iPad iOS) makes me log in every time, regardless of settings

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, authentication

Example of the problem: I log into Salesforce via my Safari mobile browser. Once logged in I select the "Home" tab in my org and click "Open in New Tab." Even though I'm opening from an existing, authenticated Salesforce tab I get the login screen again.
This happens regardless of whether or not I have Salesforce1 downloaded or whether or not I have "Salesforce1 User" checkbox selected.

I think my boss might want to have his cake and eat it too: ideally he wants to not use the downloadable app (so he can switch back and forth between SF1 and "Full Site") BUT he of course doesn't want to have to login every time he tries to open a new Salesforce tab.
Suggestions? Or is this all expected behavior and I can't really do what I'm trying to do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [private browsing](http://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT203036) turned on?

Comment: It didn't even occur to me to check @BarCotter but yes, yes it is. And now that I've turned it off things appear to be working swimmingly. Great catch!

Comment: Great. I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having [private browsing](http://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT203036) turned on will stop sessions from being shared across tabs.